# Replacing all semicolons with a space pt2

Tags: r

Im trying to run text analysis on a list of 2000+ rows of keywords, but they are listed like

"Strategy;Management Styles;Organizations"

So when I use tm to remove punctuation it becomes

"StrategyManagement StylesOrganizations"

and I assume this breaks my frequently used terms analysis some how.

Ive tried using

```
vector<-gsub(';', " ",vector)
```

but this takes my vector data "List of 2000" and makes it a value, with the description "Large character (3 elements)" when I inspected this Value it gave me a really long list of words and stuff which took forever to load! Any ideas what Im doing wrong?

Should I use gsub on my vector or on my corpus? They are just

```
vector<-VectorSource(dataset$Keywords)
corpus<-VCorpus(vector)
```

I tried using

```
inspect(corpus[[1]])
```

on my corpus after using gsub to make it a value, but I got error "no applicable method for 'inspect' applied to an object of class "character""

Comment: do you want a list of vectors of strings?

Comment: I want a vector to make it into a corpus, and then to use that for predicting which keywords belong to which field of study (like mathematics)

Comment: what are the output of: typeof(vector) and typeof(vector[[1]])

Comment: [1] "character" for both inputs

Comment: stringr::str_split(vector, ";") will return it as list of strings or unlist(stringr::str_split(vector, ";")) will return it as vector.

Comment: warning: "argument is not an atomic vector; coercing" and it still gave me the result as a value that says chr [1:5] "" "2665" "0"... no idea what that means. my original vector was 2665 observations so

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `strsplit`

```
X <- c("Global Mindset;Management","Auditor;Accounting;Selection Process","segmantation;banks;franchising")
res <- Map(function(v) unlist(strsplit(v,";")),X)
```

such that

```
> res
$`Global Mindset;Management`
[1] "Global Mindset" "Management"    

$`Auditor;Accounting;Selection Process`
[1] "Auditor"           "Accounting"        "Selection Process"

$`segmantation;banks;franchising`
[1] "segmantation" "banks"        "franchising"
```

Comment: this gave me the following error: "Error in strsplit(ncorpus, ";") : non-character argument"
i tried to strsplit my ncorpus, which is 2665 elements

Comment: @Gnubbish could you `dput()` part of your source data, otherwise it is difficult to follow the errors

Comment: trying to dput my first 10 rows gave me this error "Error in dput(texts, 10) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection"

Comment: @Gnubbish try `dput(head(texts,10))` if your `texts` is a data frame

Comment: i made it into a dataframe, where should i put the dput?  how do i post it here

Comment: @Gnubbish you copy the dput data to your post https://stackoverflow.com/q/59562363/12158757

Comment: it became a dataframe with 10 obs of 10300 variables :/ what went wrong? it was only a vector with 2 variables and 2665 obs before  ALSO the output is just nonsense and i cant even scroll to the beginning of it

Comment: @Gnubbish well....can you produce some dummy data like your real data?

Comment: looking at my dataset, the eighth row is "Global Mindset;Management" 9th is "Auditor;Accounting;Selection Process" 14th is "segmantation;banks;franchising" and so on. i have 2665 rows with different amounts of keywords in each

Comment: @Gnubbish I updated my answer, you can check if there is what you want. Since I have no exact information of your dataset, I cannot elaborate on it further

Comment: " Error in strsplit(v, ";") : non-character argument " i want to remove all semicolons from my vector. so no need to do c("Global Mindset") just do all rows

Comment: @Gnubbish Maybe you should try `gsub(";","",X)` if you just want to remove semicolons...

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the data into a vector of strings, one of the ways to do this is by using stringr package as follows;

```
library(tm)
library(stringr)

vector <- c("Strategy;Management Styles;Organizations")
keywords <- unlist(stringr::str_split(vector, ";"))

vector <- VectorSource(keywords)
corpus <- VCorpus(vector)
inspect(corpus[[1]])

#<<PlainTextDocument>>
#  Metadata:  7
#Content:  chars: 8

#Strategy
```